# Recursión con Array (java)

Tags: array, recursión

mi pregunta es si en hay alguna manera de crear una variable de ayuda en un algorítmo recursivo sin que se reinicie cada vez que se llame el metodo de forma recursiva, el ejersicio como ejemplo es contar las veces que sale un numero positivo.
mi código:(el método funciona pero mi duda simplemente es si es posible hacerlo de otra manera creando una variable de ayuda y devolverla)

```
public static int countPositives( int[] arr, int d, int t ) {
    int count = 0; // <---- esta variable me refiero
    if (t ==d) {
        if( arr[t] >0) {return 1;}
        else {return 0;}

    }
    else if(arr[t] > 0) {

        return 1+countPositives(arr,d,t-1);
    }
    else// if ( arr[t]<0) 
    return 0 + countPositives(arr,d,t-1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La variable no se reinicia, simplemente se trata de otra variable porque como es una variable local al método, cada vez que este se llama en una recursión, una nueva variable local es creada.

Para que la variable sea la misma necesitas definirla fuera del método, pero que a su vez sea visible al mismo.

Una forma de hacerlo es utilizar un atributo de la clase.

En tu ejemplo el método es estático el atributo también debe ser estático.

```
public class MiClase{
  private static int count = 0;

  public static int countPositives( int[] arr, int d, int t ) {
    if (t ==d) {
    ... // el resto del método
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, esa idea la habia pensado también pero no estaba seguro si se podia devolver una variable de fuera.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con lo del atributo y funciona perfectamente, mil gracias :)